# Build Service issue Liferay

Tags: eclipse, liferay

I'am using the liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4. I created a configuration for the Liferay Service Builder. But when I restart the Server or deploy the project, then I received the following error like in picture

How, I can solve this problem,
thanks

https://hizliresim.com/48mkzL

Comment: There is no exception in the console in the picture that you linked. Also consider uploading the pictures to stackoverflow, those external links, I would not click on all of those URLs.

Comment: might be solved here: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/60225281 - please link your next crossposts yourself